# Insert element in a priority queue, with priority attribute

Tags: java, heap, priority-queue

I have an exercise, where I have to implement a priority queue, using a min-heap.
However I cannot use the PriorityClass library, I have to implement it, by myself.
I've managed to do it by far, but, my professor, told me that my insert methods is wrong. He told me, to create an Element class, which contains 2 attributes of type T.These two attributes are (T element and T priority). How can I edit my insert method?

```
package priorityQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import priorityQueueInterfaces.PriorityQueue;


public class BinaryHeap<T> implements PriorityQueue<T> 
{
private int currentSize = 0;
private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 20;
private ArrayList<T> array = null;
private Comparator <? super T> comparator = null;

/**
 * Constructor of binary-heap
 */
public BinaryHeap(Comparator <? super T> comparator)
{
    currentSize = 0;
    array = new ArrayList<>(DEFAULT_CAPACITY + 1);
    this.comparator = comparator;
}

/**
 * Construct the binary heap from an arrayList
 */
public BinaryHeap(ArrayList<T> array, Comparator <? super T> comparator)
{
    this.currentSize = array.size();
    this.array = new ArrayList<>(array.size() + 1);
    this.comparator = comparator;

    for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
        this.array.set(i + 1, array.get(i));
}

/**
 * Method which builds the min heap with the minHeapify method
 * @throws PriorityQueueException
 */
public void buildMinHeap(ArrayList<T> array, int heapSize) throws PriorityQueueException
{
    for(int i = this.currentSize / 2; i > 0;i--)
        minHeapify(this.array,i,this.currentSize);
}

/**
 * Method which builds the max heap with the maxHeapify method
 * @throws PriorityQueueException
 */
public void buildMaxHeap() throws PriorityQueueException 
{
    for(int i = this.currentSize/2; i > 0; i--)
        maxHeapify(this.array,i,this.currentSize);
}

public void buildMaxHeap(ArrayList<T> array, int heapSize)throws PriorityQueueException
{
    if(this.array == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("ArrayList is null");
    if(this.array.size() <= 0 || heapSize <= 0 )
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Parameters: either the arraylist or the heap size are not valid");
    if(heapSize > this.array.size())
        heapSize = this.array.size();

    for(int i = heapSize/2; i > 0; i--)
        maxHeapify(this.array,i,heapSize);
}

/**
 * Insert into the priority queue.
 * Duplicates are allowed.
 * @param element is the item to insert.
 */
public void insert(T element) throws PriorityQueueException 
{
    if(element == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Element to be inserted, cannot be null!");
    if(this.size() + 1 == this.array.size())
        extendArray();

    this.currentSize = this.size() + 1;

    if(this.isEmpty())
        this.array.add(0,element);
    else
    {
        this.array.add(element);
        int index = this.size() - 1;//indice index = all'elemento appena aggiunto

        while( index > 1 && this.comparator.compare(this.array.get(index/2), this.array.get(index)) < 0)
        {
            swapElements(index, index/2);
            index = index / 2;
        }
    }
}
/**
 * @param firstIndex of the element that has to be swapped
 * @param secondIndex of the element that has to be swapped
 * @throws PriorityQueueException
 */
private void swapElements(int firstIndex,int secondIndex)throws PriorityQueueException
{
    T temp = this.array.get(firstIndex);
    this.array.set(firstIndex, this.array.get(secondIndex));
    this.array.set(secondIndex,temp);
}
}
```

**THAT'S MY ELEMENT CLASS** Which I have to use for adding an element with min-priority

```
package priorityQueue;

public class Element<T> 
{
private T element;
private T priority;

public Element(T element,T priority)
{
    this.element = element;
    this.priority = priority;
}

public void setElement(T element)
{
    this.element = element;
}

public void setPriority(T priority)
{
    this.priority = priority;
}

public T getElement()
{
    return this.element;
}

public T getPriority()
{
    return this.priority;
}
}
```

**My method of insert works just fine, but i have to insert also the priority contained in the class element. How to do it?**

Comment: Does the Comparator that u pass in consider priority before swap and balance the heap.

Comment: @user1653941No it'doesn't

Comment: You have the same type for both priority and element attributes, it shud be public class Element<T,X> ?. Then consider the priority in the compare logic, when the elements are compared.

Comment: @user1653941 could you please write some code?